# Многозначный словарь

Tags: c#

Подскажите как добавить ещё один `string` в словарь `Dictionary`?

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> multi = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Чтобы было 3 поля.

---

Спасибо за подсказку про `Tuple<T>`

```
public static Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> multi = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<string, string>> test in multi)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(test.Key);
    // test.Value.Item1, test.Value.Item2
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static Dictionary<string, (string, string)> multi = new Dictionary<string, (string, string)>();
```

Comment: А не прибегаю к установке дополнительной библиотеки, есть возможность? Просто тут нужно устанавливать `System.ValueTuple.dll` У меня версия `.Net 4.0` - нужно именно на этой

Comment: Ну сам структуру из двух полей заведи. Или используй обычный классовый `Tuple<string, string>`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да можно и обычным массивом

Comment: Можно массивом, можно списком, можно кортежем, можно свой класс или структуру сделать.

Comment: @Grundy, думаю, на массив накладные расходы больше, чем на классовый Tuple.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, обновил вопрос.

Comment: @AndreyVasiliykov нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы установить библиотеку

Comment: @AndreyVasiliykov кстати, у этой библиотеки исходники открытые, их можно к себе скопировать (с сохранением лицензии)

Comment: @AndreyVasiliykov вот исходник: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueTuple.cs

Comment: @PavelMayorov, полезно, спасибо!